# Private chat in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, chat, private

I want to create chat (like Facebook or google) on my ASP.NET website using c#.

My project have users database and user will login to use chat feature.

Can any one help me how to achieve this one.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SignalR, this Git Repo has a solution all setup i believe.

[Git hub repo of SignalR](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR)

Or follow ths youtube video

[Youtube video of how to do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76XoV23I5YY)

I have seen a live demo on how to set it up once, and it took the presenter 5 minutes to get it setup